# Infinite strip pattern Symmetry Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having trouble applying the proposition demonstrated below to the proof. I understand up to the point in which you use the propostion. I also understand that geometrically στ=τσ, but why does this imply G(Π) is abelian?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G(\Pi)$ is generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$, if these generators commute, then so will every pair of elements.  For instance, since
$$
\tau^2 \sigma = \tau \tau \sigma = \tau \sigma \tau = \sigma \tau \tau = \sigma \tau^2
$$
then $\tau^2$ and $\sigma$ commute.  You can use induction to show that $\sigma$ and $\tau^n$ commute for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  Then use this result to show that $\sigma$ and $\tau^n$ commute for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Once you've shown that, recall that the solution above showed that all elements of $G(\Pi)$ are of the form $\tau^n$ or $\tau^n \sigma$.  So we have to check that elements of this form commute.  I won't do all the cases, but note that
\begin{align*}
\tau^n \sigma \tau^m \sigma &= \sigma \tau^n \tau^m \sigma = \sigma \tau^{m+n} \sigma = \sigma \tau^m \tau^n \sigma = \tau^m \sigma \tau^n \sigma
\end{align*}
so elements of the form $\tau^n \sigma$ commute with each other.  The other cases aren't very different.